# Volley: param.put with two for loop not working correctly

Tags: android-volley

i have two arraylist like below

```
final ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
final ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
```

i added values into arralist as below

```
    numbers.add(m,""+phoneNumber);
    names.add(m,name);
    // m is index start from 0, i used while loop for that
```

numbers containing 949 rows and names also 949  rows

i am sending request using Stringrequest

following is my sending data, sending method is post

```
@Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> param=new HashMap<String, String>();

                for (int z=0;z<names.size();z++)
                {
                    param.put("names["+z+"]",names.get(z).toString();

                }
                for (int z1=0;z1<numbers.size();z1++)
                {
                    param.put("numbers["+z1+"]",numbers.get(z1).toString());

                }


                return param;
            }
```

from php server when i return total rows of numbers and names

```
example: echo count($numbers).":"$names;
```

response comes as 
508:493

but when i use only one for loop like below and return param then response count is 949 as i expected,

```
for (int z=0;z<names.size();z++)
                {
                    param.put("names["+z+"]",names.get(z).toString();

                }
```

BUT when i use BOTH for loop at a time again its not sending data correctly,

what is problem here?